# Workflow in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workflow

We have a document library hosted in Sharepoint Online with a single stage workflow attached that simply logs a few things and calls a web service. The workflow is triggered automatically when an item is updated.

The issue that we're having is that the documents are openned and changed in Word Online, which streams changes back to Sharepoint as they are made. This triggers the update event, but the document is still locked in Word Online so Sharepoint cannot even read the document metadata and the workflow hangs as a result. I need access to this metadata to pass to the web service.

The error is as follows:

Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute. Details of last request: HTTP 423 to https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/etc/etc

The file "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/test/Documents/test12311.docx" is locked for shared use by .

...and the action that it hangs on is:

Log The file [%Current Item:ID%]  has bee... to the workflow history list

Once the browser tab is closed the lock is removed and the workflow completes.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?